# Smooth out array of increasing numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, numbers

I have array of values like below

[100,190,290,395,500,**800**,700,800,**600**,1020]

Here I have sets of numbers with increasing numbers , but here there is two odd numbers when i plot it as graph , 800 and 600  , both should be replaced something like 610 and 900 respectively.

How can I achieve it.

Note : There will be maximum two odd numbers in a row , in total of minumum of 10 numbers

Comment: what's the rule for the substitution? why `610` and `900` instead of, let say, `669` and `972`? Why not simply discard them?

Comment: it should be some where like average of previous and next number (500+700)/2

Comment: Please note that even next number too can be odd one , so need to find series of numbers first based on increasing average

Comment: what should be the output for `[100, 300, 10, 20, 30]` with odd values at the end? what for `[100, 10, 20, 30, 300]`?  Maybe including some scenarios in your question with an explanation for each case could be useful.

Comment: there will be maximum two odd numbers in a row , in total of 10 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Simple algorithm without checking the edge cases:

```js
let input = [100,190,290,395,500,800,700,800,600,1020];
let odds = input.filter(( item, index) =>  
   (item > input[index -1] && item > input[index + 1]) || 
   (item < input[index -1] && item < input[index + 1]));
let indices = odds.map( (item) => input.indexOf(item));
console.log(indices);
indices.forEach( i => {
 input[i] = (input[i-1] + input [i+1])/2;
});
//input now is [100, 190, 290, 395, 500, 600, 700, 800, 910, 1020]
console.log(input);
```

Comment: hi , input should be something like 395,500,600,700,800,910, 1020

Comment: let input = [100,2,290,395,10000,100000,700,800,900,1020];
, this thing is messing the input

Comment: I have an idea , to find the difference between all prev and next ,,, here average of 100 is most common in many scenarios , so we must use that to find odd numbers I guess.

Comment: @Graciewilliams, as I said, this is the simple idea. It depends on your own logic to filter what you considered as ODD items. You can adapt this with whatever your own criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to replace the anomalies `800` and `600` with `600` and `910` because they are the averages of the two adjacent elements in the array. You can solve this with a one liner as such:

```js
const input = [100, 190, 290, 395, 500, 800, 700, 800, 600, 1020];
input.map((val, i, arr) => [0, arr.length-1].includes(i) || (val-arr[i-1])*(val-arr[i+1]) <= 0 ? val : (arr[i-1] + arr[i+1])/2 )
// [ 100, 190, 290, 395, 500, 600, 800, 650, 910, 1020 ]
```

Brief explanation:

```
[0, arr.length-1].includes(i)
```

checks if current element isn't the first or the last of the array (in which case we can't compare with values on both sides) and

```js
(val-arr[i-1])*(val-arr[i+1]) <= 0
```

checks wether the number is between the two adjacent elements in the array.